# How to Transpose an Array of Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have this array of objects structure:

```
arr = [
{seat: [{available: false, id: 1},{available: false, id: 5},{available: true, id: 9},{available: true, id: 13},{available: true, id: 17},{available: true, id: 21},{available: true, id: 25},{available: true, id: 29},{available: true, id: 33},{available: true, id: 37},{available: true, id: 41}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 2},{available: true, id: 6},{available: true, id: 10},{available: true, id: 14},{available: true, id: 18},{available: true, id: 22},{available: true, id: 26},{available: true, id: 30},{available: true, id: 34},{available: true, id: 38},{available: true, id: 42}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 3},{available: false, id: 7},{available: true, id: 11},{available: true, id: 15},{available: true, id: 19},{available: true, id: 23},{available: true, id: 27},{available: true, id: 31},{available: true, id: 35},{available: true, id: 39},{available: true, id: 43}, {available: true, id: 45},{available: true, id: 47}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 4},{available: true, id: 8},{available: false, id: 12},{available: true, id: 16},{available: true, id: 20},{available: true, id: 24},{available: true, id: 28},{available: true, id: 32},{available: true, id: 36},{available: true, id: 40},{available: true, id: 44},{available: true, id: 46},{available: true, id: 48}]},
]
```

And I need to have a row of seats every 4 seats:

```
[
{seat: [{available: false, id: 1},{available: true, id: 2},{available: true, id: 3},{available: true, id: 4}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 5},{available: false, id: 6},{available: true, id: 7},{available: true, id: 8}]},
{seat: [{available: false, id: 9},{available: true, id: 10},{available: true, id: 11},{available: true, id: 12}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 13},{available: true, id: 14},{available: false, id: 15},{available: true, id: 16}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 17},{available: true, id: 18},{available: false, id: 19},{available: true, id: 20}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 21},{available: true, id: 22},{available: false, id: 23},{available: true, id: 24}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 25},{available: true, id: 26},{available: false, id: 27},{available: true, id: 28}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 29},{available: true, id: 30},{available: false, id: 31},{available: true, id: 32}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 33},{available: true, id: 34},{available: false, id: 35},{available: true, id: 36}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 37},{available: true, id: 38},{available: false, id: 39},{available: true, id: 40}]},
{seat: [{available: true, id: 41},{available: true, id: 42},{available: false, id: 43},{available: true, id: 44}]},
{seat: [{available: false, id: null},{available: false, id: null},{available: false, id: 45},{available: true, id: 46}]},
{seat: [{available: false, id: null},{available: false, id: null},{available: false, id: 47},{available: true, id: 48}]},
]
```

Notice that the third and fourth seat object has more seats than the first and second one, so in the last two seat rows from the output, it has null values because there are no seats from the first and second rows
I tried this:

```
const transpose = (data) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          const tmp = data[i][j];
          data[i][j] = data[j][i];
          data[j][i] = tmp;
        }
      }
    };
transpose(arr);
```

but that outputs everything wrong, this is for seat selection on a plane, so the database is returning every 3 columns, but to print it on a grid I need that columns to be regular rows... or maybe if you know a better way to map the seats vertically (it is an app)

Thanks in advance for your response!

[Pastebin with the full structure of array](https://pastebin.com/TEy9k2FB)https://pastebin.com/TEy9k2FB

EDIT: structure typos, pastebin with the full structure
EDIT 2: changed the structure of the question, not transposing anymore

Comment: do you mean sort by id?

Comment: @Nonik basically

Comment: `[seat: [] ]` is not valid javascript. Did you mean `{seat: [] }`?

Comment: @terrymorse yes, sorry

Comment: Will there always be 12 ids, numbered 1-12?

Comment: @kmoser no, actually that is always variable, there are planes with less than 40 seats, more than 40 seats, so yeah, more between 30 and 50 id's, but always 4 columns.

Comment: You don't need to transpose the data. Just swap the order of the loops when displaying the seats. `for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) { for i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) ... } }`

Comment: Are the `seat` arrays always equally sized?

Comment: @trincot this is the pastebin https://pastebin.com/TEy9k2FB with all the seats arrays, is really big, always 4 seat objects with variable number of seats

Comment: OK, can you edit your question and give an example where the `seat` arrays have different sizes (not like you currently have arrays that all have 3 items), and what then the result should be of the transposition? This is open to interpretation...

Comment: @trincot I changed the whole question, thank you!

Comment: Can you complete the desired output. I am curious how the "and so on" ends...

Comment: @trincot Done :)

Comment: Thanks! I posted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this. Here is a function that creates a new data structure and returns it. It first finds out what is the largest size of a `seat` array in the input, using `Math.max`. Then it creates an array with that many rows, using `Array.from`. Each generated row is populated with as many items as there are rows in the original data (4).

When there is no corresponding item to transpose, a default one is used instead (using `??` operator).

```js
const transpose = arr =>
    Array.from({length: Math.max(...arr.map(({seat}) => seat.length))}, (_, i) =>
        ({ seat: arr.map(({seat}) => seat[i] ?? {available: false, id: null}) })
    );

// The sample data from the question:
const arr = [{seat: [{available: false, id: 1},{available: false, id: 5},{available: true, id: 9},{available: true, id: 13},{available: true, id: 17},{available: true, id: 21},{available: true, id: 25},{available: true, id: 29},{available: true, id: 33},{available: true, id: 37},{available: true, id: 41}]},{seat: [{available: true, id: 2},{available: true, id: 6},{available: true, id: 10},{available: true, id: 14},{available: true, id: 18},{available: true, id: 22},{available: true, id: 26},{available: true, id: 30},{available: true, id: 34},{available: true, id: 38},{available: true, id: 42}]},{seat: [{available: true, id: 3},{available: false, id: 7},{available: true, id: 11},{available: true, id: 15},{available: true, id: 19},{available: true, id: 23},{available: true, id: 27},{available: true, id: 31},{available: true, id: 35},{available: true, id: 39},{available: true, id: 43}, {available: true, id: 45},{available: true, id: 47}]},{seat: [{available: true, id: 4},{available: true, id: 8},{available: false, id: 12},{available: true, id: 16},{available: true, id: 20},{available: true, id: 24},{available: true, id: 28},{available: true, id: 32},{available: true, id: 36},{available: true, id: 40},{available: true, id: 44},{available: true, id: 46},{available: true, id: 48}]},]

const result = transpose(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In order for this transformation matrix algorithm to work, it operates on the assumption that every "cell" is present... filled or not. I.e. every row has the same length and every column has the same length.
2. You made a small error in your code... this should be the fix(?).

Your code:

```
const transpose = (data) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          const tmp = data[i][j];
          data[i][j] = data[j][i];
          data[j][i] = tmp;
        }
      }
    };
transpose(arr);
```

A few observations as to why it didn't work:
The second loop looped up to the value of i and not the value of `data[i].length`. Another potential problem is how you change the values in the matrix. If you try to loop over your input data while replacing the data in the same matrix at the same time, you will ruin your input data, and thus end up with a bad matrix. Think about your algorithm with some simple data like a 2x3 matrix, and this becomes more apparent.

```js
myArray = [["apples","apples","apples"],["bananas","bananas","bananas"], ["carrots","carrots","carrots"]]

function transpose(data)
{
  tmpAr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    tmpAr.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)
    {
      tmpAr[i].push(data[j][i]);
    }
  }
  return tmpAr;
}

console.log(myArray)
console.log(transpose(myArray))
```